# Validation not working correctly in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I have some fields with images, I want to do an update to the database only if there is an image. I have tried setting to nullable but I keep on getting error the photo must be of type image.
This is my code in Livewire class:

```
 $this->validate([
     'photo1'=>'sometimes|image',
     'photo2'=>'nullable|image',
     'photo3'=>'nullable|image'
    ]);
```

In the  blade

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Front Right</label>
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo1" accept="image/*">
        <span class="text-danger">@error('photo1'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Flont Left</label>
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo2" accept="image/*">
      <span class="text-danger">@error('photo2'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check your request data, you can use ```dd($request)``` or just return all data ```return $request->all()```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's bit late for it, but I had the same issue and this is the solution:

If you are using updated instead of updating it will work. The problem when using updating is that the property does not have the file assigned, so it's still null during validation.

Let's say your are using updating() and your property name is $logo:

You would need to assign the $value to the property ($logo) before validation, e.g.:

```
function updating($key,$value) {
  $this-logo = $value; // This line you need to add to make it work
  $this-validateOnly($key);
}
```

I do simply use updated() instead.

Answer (score -1):

Have you added **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form element?
Add mimes in validation: 'photo2'=>'nullable|image|**mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif**' and then check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your response I still get the error The photo2 must be an image. It is like it like validation is showing always required